# How to show my app notification on lock screen programmatically, below lollipop version

Tags: android, notifications

How to show my app notification on lock screen programmatically ,below lollipop version without installing 3rd party solutions such as NiLS Lock Screen Notifications .

Comment: Are you looking for Media Session Compat?